# Launching a rosbag record node on a remote machine

Tags: ros-melodic, roslaunch, rosbag, network, remote-launch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to launch a rosbag record node on a remote machine. The reason why I'm trying to do this, is because I want to have a synchronous recording of topics on two different machines. I am aware, that I could just record all topics on one machine, however, for some reason I am missing data, when I am doing so (if you have suggestions on how to solve that, I'd be happy to hear about them, too). My launch file `record_bags.launch` looks like this:

```
<launch>
    <machine name="comp2" address="10.0.0.1" user="user" env-loader="/home/user/catkin_ws/devel/remote_env_load.bash" default="false" />
    <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_kinect" machine="comp2" respawn="false" output="screen" args="--duration=5 -O /home/user/test.bag /topic3 /topic4" />
    <node pkg="rosbag" type="record" name="record_atis" respawn="false" output="screen" args="--duration=5 -O /home/user/test.bag /topic1 /topic2" />
</launch>
```

The remote_env_load.bash on the remote machine "comp2" looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
export ROS_IP=10.0.0.1
export ROS_MASTER_URI=10.0.0.2
source /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash
source /home/user/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash
```

Now when I use `roslaunch record_bags.launch` I get the following error:

```
error launching on [10.0.0.1-0, uri http://10.0.0.1:41387/]: ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/server.py", line 332, in launch
    succeeded, failed = runner.launch()
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 662, in launch
    self._setup()
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 637, in _setup
    launched = self._launch_master()
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 400, in _launch_master
    validate_master_launch(m, self.is_core, self.is_rostest)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/launch.py", line 83, in validate_master_launch
    if not rosgraph.network.is_local_address(m.get_host()):
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/roslaunch/core.py", line 273, in get_host
    host, _ = rosgraph.network.parse_http_host_and_port(self.uri)
  File "/opt/ros/melodic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rosgraph/network.py", line 91, in parse_http_host_and_port
    raise ValueError('not a valid URL')
ValueError: not a valid URL

Launch of the following nodes most likely failed: rosbag/record
```

Does anyone have an idea on what is going wrong here?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344888/launching-a-rosbag-record-node-on-a-remote-machine/) by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2020-02-24

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> ```
> export ROS_MASTER_URI=10.0.0.2
> ```

As the name of the variable implies, it should be set to a full URI, not just an IP.

So it should most likely be:

```
export ROS_MASTER_URI=http://10.0.0.2:11311
```

in your case.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-02-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2020-02-24**:
Great thanks. If you don't mind, I'd have another little question to append: Is there a way to make sure these to records will start at the exact same time?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-24**:\

> If you don't mind, I'd have another little question to append

actually: posting follow-up questions in comments on accepted answers is a bad idea. They have very low visibility. It'd be better to post a new question (and potentially referring back to this one in your new post).

**Comment by [max11gen](https://answers.ros.org/users/38506/max11gen/) on 2020-02-24**:
You are right. I just posted another question. Thanks for your help, and feel free to remove these comments.